# Matlab 'sendmail' body text is misaligned

Tags: html, matlab, sendmail, text-alignment, document-body

Hi I am using Matlab to send an automated email. The body text of the mail appears
correctly justified (aligned) in Matlab Command Window, but when email is sent out alignment is broken and text is not correctly aligned. Any help is really appreciated. Thank you

Comment: Your question is short on details, but I suspect it's most likely because the command window is using a monospaced font, whereas the actual email isn't.

Comment: Yes, this is exactly the problem, any ideas on how to fix that? Possibly change email font to monospaced font? Thank you, Marios

Comment: I recommend to use html instead to format the email.

Comment: Is there a link with information on how to use html with matlab?